# How to use import on some files and use require in other files in the same project

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs project that has the following items in package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
  "express": "^4.18.2",
  "ipfs-http-client": "^60.0.0",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
  "lodash": "^4.17.21",
  "moment": "^2.29.4",
}
```

}

In all of my js files, I always do a `require` to load the modules, for example:

```
const moment = require("moment");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const fs = require("fs");
```

Everything is ok until I need to use the latest version of `ipfs-http-client` module.  If I do `const client = require("ipfs-http-client");`, then I will get this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:544
  throw e;
  ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /myproj/node_modules/ipfs-http-client/package.json
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
```

So I use `import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'` instead of `require`, but I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1182:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

To solve this, I add `type="module"` in `package.json`. The js file that imports `ipfs-http-client` finally works without error.  However, all my other js files complain with error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension
```

I cannot change all of them to use `import` just for this one module that requires me to use `import` instead of `require`.  How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the format file from `.js` to `.mjs`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by including information on how this solution works.

Comment: I changed the extension of the file that contains the `import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'` to `.mjs`.  I was able to run that, let's say `test.mjs` in solitary.  But I need to require that into my `app.js` file as follows:  `const test = require("./test");`.  This time, when I run `app.js`, I got `Error: Cannot find module './test'... code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'`